# Probability Trick Question

Tags: probability

> Rihanna puts 9 pairs of blue socks and 8 pairs of grey socks in a drawer. She picks up 3 socks. Calculate the probability that she will pick up a pair of blue socks?

This question was left by my teacher after our lecture about probability. I searched the internet for answer, I found one but I really don't understand where $\frac6{11}$, which is the answer, came from.

Comment: are socks pairs same

Answer (score 5):

Think of it as if the socks are picked up one by one.$$P(bbb)+P(bbg)+P(bgb)+P(gbb)=$$$$\frac{18}{34}\frac{17}{33}\frac{16}{32}+\frac{18}{34}\frac{17}{33}\frac{16}{32}+\frac{18}{34}\frac{16}{33}\frac{17}{32}+\frac{16}{34}\frac{18}{33}\frac{17}{32}=$$$$\frac{18}{34}\frac{17}{33}\frac{16}{32}+3\cdot\frac{18}{34}\frac{17}{33}\frac{16}{32}=4\cdot\frac{18}{34}\frac{17}{33}\frac{16}{32}=\frac6{11}$$

Comment: 9 * 2 = 18, the total number of blue socks. 8 * 2 = 16, the total number of grey socks. 18 + 16 = 34, the total number of all the socks. Now I'm confused where 17, 32, and 33 came from. (I'm so stupid, sorry T.T)

Comment: After picking e.g. one blue sock as first the situation has changed. In total $33$ socks are left of which $17$ are blue.

Comment: Ahh okay, now I get it. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

The "trick" of the question's title is probably in specifying the numbers of socks as pairs: Rihanna really has 18 blue and 16 grey socks with no distinction between "left" and "right" of a pair. Now the probability she picks up at least two blue socks in her selection of three *without replacement* is given by the hypergeometric distribution as
$$\frac{\binom{18}2\binom{16}1+\binom{18}3\binom{16}0}{\binom{34}3}=\frac6{11}$$
which matches the given answer.